# Pygame moving an image in a direction

Tags: python, pygame

This is my first post here and I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me how to move an image to a point.  Here's my code:

```
class bullet:

image = "bullet.png"
spr = pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha()
x = 0
y = 0
def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.x = a
    self.y = b

    while self.x > 0 and self.x < 500 and self.y > 0 and self.y < 500:#the boundries for the bullet
    CODE GOES IN HERE TO MOVE IMAGE
```

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: I haven't set it up to work yet as i don't know how to do it, therefor no errors.

Comment: @utility I need to get the code to implement it.  Sorry if i can't be enough help.  If you need any more code, let me know.

Comment: @sloth this isnt a duplacate as I need to move the image in a direction.  Such as 79 degrees.  So if the mouse is clicked, it would move towards it, but not stop at the mouse, and the mouse can move.

Comment: @sloth Yes, but I assume you would set up something different, as it would take a different setup to move to a point than moving in a direction.

Comment: @sloth but it would still vary in a big way, due to the fact that instead of using a point, I would find the value of direction then use that.  But if you think setting a vector first using the mouse would work, then could you tell me how to do it please? :) Thanks

Comment: @sloth  Thanks, and I did see that before.  But could you please tell me how it works.  I don't think I was sure how it actually applied to my scenario.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but I would also need to move it in other angles, I simply used 79 as an example.  Thanks, MLGjediNOSCOPE

Comment: I recommend using some basic trigonometry, and assigning variables to the sprite that tell it how far to move vertically and horizontally. This requires the use of atan2 and center positions for the sprite. The sprite image will need to be rotated based on atan2. In the update() function, place a conditional statement that increments the sprites position based on whether or not it has reached its destination and then blit the sprite and redraw the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this example:

```
import pygame
import base64
import math
import random

# some functions for vector math

def magnitude(v):
    return math.sqrt(sum(v[i]*v[i] for i in range(len(v))))

def add(u, v):
    return [(a+b) for (a, b) in zip(u, v)]

def sub(u, v):
    return [(a-b) for (a, b) in zip(u, v)]

def dot(u, v):
    return sum((a*b) for a, b in zip(u, v))

def normalize(v):
    vmag = magnitude(v)
    return [ v[i]/vmag  for i in range(len(v)) ]

def length(v):
  return math.sqrt(dot(v, v))

def angle(v1, v2):
  return math.acos(dot(v1, v2) / (length(v1) * length(v2)))

def get_image():
    dec = base64.b64decode(img, 'UTF-8')
    surf = pygame.image.fromstring(dec, (32, 32), 'RGBA')
    return surf

def rot_center(image, angle):
    orig_rect = image.get_rect()
    rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    rot_rect = orig_rect.copy()
    rot_rect.center = rot_image.get_rect().center
    rot_image = rot_image.subsurface(rot_rect).copy()
    return rot_image

class Actor(object):

    surf = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.x, self.y = (0, 0)
        self.speed, self.angle = 1.7, 0
        self.target_vector = [0, 0]

    @property
    def img(self):
        if not self.surf:
            self.surf = get_image()
        return self.surf


    @property
    def pos(self):
        return self.x, self.y

    @property
    def int_pos(self):
        return map(int, self.pos)

    @property
    def center_pos(self):
        return [a-16 for a in self.int_pos]

    def update(self):
        if self.speed == 0:
            return

        # apply speed to target_vector
        move_vector = [c * self.speed for c in normalize(self.target_vector)]

        # update position by adding the position vector to the movment vector
        self.x, self.y = add(self.pos, move_vector)

    def draw(self, s):
        s.blit(rot_center(self.img, self.angle), self.center_pos)

def fire(start, angle, target_vector):
    act = Actor()
    act.x, act.y = start
    act.angle = angle
    act.target_vector = target_vector
    return act

def main():    
    pygame.init()
    quit = False
    s = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
    c = pygame.time.Clock()
    pos = (134, 268)
    actors = []
    FIRE = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    pygame.time.set_timer(FIRE, 1000)
    while not quit:

        quit = pygame.event.get(pygame.QUIT)

        if pygame.event.get(FIRE):
            angle = random.randint(0, 180)
            print 'angle is ', angle
            # calculate vector that represents the direction
            rangle = math.radians(-angle)
            target_vector = normalize((math.cos(rangle), math.sin(rangle)))
            actors.append(fire(pos, angle, target_vector))

        pygame.event.poll()
        for ar in actors:
            ar.update()
        s.fill((255, 255, 255))
        for ar in actors:
            ar.draw(s)
        pygame.display.flip()
        c.tick(60)

img = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAOwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFEAAADUAAAAXgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAP8AAADTAAAAVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABQAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAAhQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFAAAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAAdwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAApwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABQAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAAnwAAAAUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFAAAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAAxQAAAAYAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAAywAAAA4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABLAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAA3QAAABUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACHAAAAhwAAAIcAAACHAAAAhwAAAIcAAACHAAAAhwAAAIcAAACHAAAAhwAAAIcAAACHAAAAhgAAAK0AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAA7wAAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAA7wAAAC8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAADwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAAUgAAAFMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAGQAAAAAAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAIAAAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAAggAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAGUAAAAAAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAPoAAABUAAAAAAAAAAAAAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAAPgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAA7wAAADAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAhwAAAIcAAACHAAAAhwAAAIcAAACHAAAAhwAAAIcAAACHAAAAhwAAAIcAAACHAAAAhwAAAIYAAACtAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAPAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEsAAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADdAAAAFQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAAywAAAA4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABQAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAMUAAAAGAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFAAAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAACgAAAABQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAAqAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABQAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAHgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFAAAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAACFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAP8AAADTAAAAVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABRAAAATgAAAF4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD4AAAA7AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=='

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here, a random angle is converted to a vector which is used to move an object.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  However, i don't under stand it.  Can you please explain?  Thanks!

Comment: @MLGjediNOSCOPE What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: how do vectors work, why do you need to find the square root in the first function, what's base64, and which bits do what?  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I can't really explain vector math in this answer. That's something you usually learn in school. Maybe you could read it up yourself. The same goes for base64. Wikipedia should be a good starting point. If you want to create a graphical game, you just need some basic math knowledge (vectors/geometry etc.). It isn't that hard, really.

Comment: Thanks anyway.  I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a screen to set up the display:

```
size = (640, 480) # window size
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size) # screen where the image will be displayed
```

You need to use the screen.blit to display the image. It takes the image object and x,y coordinates as parameters. In your case it should be like:

```
screen.blit(spr, (x,y)) # draws image at x,y coordinate
```

Comment: Thank you.  However, I need to get the x and y co ordinates to change to go in a line.